# Best way to encourage grass to grow through dirt?

Tags: lawn, grass, lawn-repair

I recently had a patio put in, and because my lawn had more of slope than the installed patio they used the dirt from the excavation to level the lawn to the patio.

I had originally thought that I would have to re-seed this patch of dirt, but it appears that the grass below is starting to come through, so I am thinking that maybe just a “wait and see” approach may work.

Is it reasonable to think that nature will find a way and that the grass will grow through the dirt to the point where it looks like a normal lawn?  If so, are there any tips and tricks I can use to encourage the process? Or, should I just go for the re-seeding approach?

[image]

Comment: How deep was the new layer of dirt? Anything more than an inch or two will probably kill most of the old grass.

Comment: @alephzero It’s definitely 1-2 inches in places. Also, upon closer inspection, some of it is pretty hard, almost clay-like. I wouldn’t expect anything to grow through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rake with an iron rake ( not a spring type ), you want to pull grass leaves up to the surface. I put 1 to 2 inches of sand in the back yard and it worked well . I have St Augustine which can be put in with plugs so it may have tolerated it better than some other grasses.

Comment: The dirt was too deep in most places for this to work, but I had other spots where this worked quite well.